# Why do ball bearings work?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction

I am trying to develop a simple conceptual explanation for why ball bearings are so effective, but I am not sure if I am on the right track.

My short explanation is that a ball bearing allows us to trade a coefficient of kinetic friction for a coefficient of rolling resistance, and coefficients of rolling resistance are typically much smaller than coefficients of kinetic friction.

My simple understanding is that balls roll without slipping along both the inner and outer radius of the bearing. This would produce no resistance on the axle if it weren't for the rolling resistance of the balls. Thus, the only torque passed on to the axis is proportional to the load the balls are under times their coefficient of rolling resistance. The alternative would be the axle rubbing against the shaft, which would be proportional to load times coefficient of kinetic friction which would be much larger.

Is this a correct mental model for how ball bearings work?

Comment: That's a good description of ball bearings: rolling instead of sliding

Comment: so efficiency, along with lower wear, and thus maintenance and cost

Comment: Some material properties might be worth considering, too. There's always some degree of distortion in the shape of something under load. That distortion introduces altered moments of inertia and sources of friction. I think the effect one be smaller for spheres.

Comment: You're over complicating a bit by looking at ball bearings specifically. It's a lot more straightforward to just look at wheels rolling on a flat surface horizontal and compare that to the force required if the wheels were not there.

Comment: @DKNguyen I understand wheels but the connection between ball bearings and wheels was not intuitive right away. It took me a while to visualize what the balls are doing inside the bearing and to confirm mathematically that they can roll without slipping between the two surfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. Let's have a closer look.

Because (as you point out) you can make the coefficient of rolling friction practically as small as you want, and geometrically enforce the no-slip condition by the design of the bearing balls and races, this also means that the bearing will not wear out by scuffing material off of the sliding surfaces as happens in a *plain bearing* in which one sliding surface is chosen to be softer than the other and thereby takes all the wear- and requires replacement.

In fact, as a brand-new ball bearing rotates its primary frictional loss mechanism is the stirring of the oil inside it (and not from the balls and races themselves).
These are called *windage losses*.

Even if one of the big ball or roller bearings as used on the crankshaft of a Suzuki GS1000 racing motorcycle engine loses its lubrication source in the course of a race, the "dry-running" bearing will still last long enough to finish the race
whereas a plain main bearing run dry at 14,000 RPM would burn up and catastrophically sieze after a few miles.

Comment: Is there friction from adjacent balls rolling on each other?

Comment: there is no contact between adjacent balls

Answer (score 0):

It is a good description.

I would add that if the ball were between two plane surfaces, the relative velocity $v$ between them would determine the angular velocity of the ball with radius $r$: $r\omega = v$.

But with the ball between 2 circles of different diameters (inner and outer race), there is a relative angular velocity between them. In the formula $r\omega = v$, the tangential velocity of the ball is the same for both races.

If there is no slide in the inner race, there will be some slide in the outer race because, for a given angular displacement of the ball, the length of contact in the latter is bigger than in the former.

But there is of course much smaller kinetic friction than in plain bearings.